# Saving and retrieving files in Codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I have an app with data files (some images and xml files) i have packed them up in a zip file.

I open the file with zipme  and save the files. I used this code for that

```
private void save1( ) {
      InputStream is;
         FileChooser.showOpenDialog(".zip", new ActionListener() {
                 @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                  if (e != null && e.getSource() != null) {
                    String file = (String)e.getSource();
                    FileSystemStorage fs = FileSystemStorage.getInstance();
                  try {
                      InputStream is  = fs.openInputStream(file);
                      ZipInputStream zipStream = new ZipInputStream(is);
                      ZipEntry entry;

                       // create a buffer to improve copy performance later.
                       byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
                        while ((entry = zipStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                          String s = entry.getName();
                          String outdir = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getAppHomePath();
                          if (outdir.length() > 0) {
                              outdir = outdir  ;
                          }
                          String outpath = outdir   + "/" +  entry.getName();
                          OutputStream output = null;
                          try {
                              output = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openOutputStream(outpath);
                              int len = 0;
                              while ((len = zipStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                                  output.write(buffer, 0, len);
                             }

                          } finally {
                              // we must always close the output file
                              if (output != null) {
                                  output.close();
                              }
                          }
                        } } catch (IOException ex) {
  Log.p(ex.getMessage(), 0); }                 }      }});}
```

i see in netbeans that in the simulator the files are saved  to
users/.cn1
So this works on the desktop

To fetch the image i use

String outdir = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getAppHomePath();
Image uur1 = EncodedImage.create(outdir + "/West.jpg");

i also tried without outdir but also no luck.
What do i wrong.

Comment: This should work without the extra slash: `Image uur1 = EncodedImage.create(outdir + "West.jpg");`. Notice that this code is case sensitive so make sure the file has the right casing. Is this failing on the simulator, if so place a breakpoint on the loading code and make sure the file is physically there.

Comment: Thanx Shai , i solved my problem  The extra slash was a problem. I also noticed that i have to make a inputstream and than put in the encodedimage.create(inputstream) only the location string doesn't work  Another question, when i put  files in the filesystemstorage. files with the same name will be overwritten?

Comment: I don't understand any of those questions. Can you elaborate with a sample? Ideally file a different question. I'll add an answer here so you can accept it and get points for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer i found on my question is:
1 No extra slash as Shai Among suggested:
2 Make a inputstream for enecodedimage.create() instead of only a string with the path to the file

Without the second part the app doesn't run correctly in the simulation and on the device

```
FileSystemStorage fs = FileSystemStorage.getInstance();       
String outdir = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getAppHomePath();
String outpath = outdir + West.jpg;
InputStream isk   = fs.openInputStream(outpath);   
Image uur = EncodedImage.create(isk);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work without the extra slash:

```
Image uur1 = EncodedImage.create(outdir + "West.jpg");.
```

Notice that this code is case sensitive so make sure the file has the right casing. Is this failing on the simulator, if so place a breakpoint on the loading code and make sure the file is physically there